# How to predit in chrome extension html before it is displayed

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension that is also supposed to remove parts of HTML.Thing is, I need to do that when I receive the html from the server BUT before it is displayed.If I use run at for document end and try to modify the HTML it'll look ugly because the page will load and then change, and I want to remove html parts and edit them before it is displayed.

For example, if my extension will need to clear the whole body tag I will need a script like that in runbefore.js:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "";
```

But when I use content scripts -

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.website.com/*"],
      "js": ["runbefore.js"],
      "run_at":    "document_end"
    }
```

It loads the page and only then clears the whole page, and I want to clear the body tag and only then display it.If I use document_start it won't even do anything.

How do I resolve that issue ?

Comment: Use document_start and MutationObserver.

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: No idea if JavaScript lets you do this, but couldn't you hide the body, do what you need to do, and at the need of whatever you need to do, display it again?

Answer (score 0):

You can change `run_at` property in your manifest to `document_start` in your manifest.

You can get more information about this property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts).